# android onItemClick silently fails

Tags: android

I'm displaying some sql data in a list via a ListAdapter. Everything works fine except when I try to set a click listener to each item in the list. Nothing happens when I click any of the items; no error messages, it just silently fails.

```
public class Notes extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "Notes";
    private NotesData notes;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        notes = new NotesData(this);
        try {
            Cursor cursor = getNotes();
            showNotes(cursor); /* set the cursor to the listadapter */
            ListView ls = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
            ls.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,View v,
                    int position,long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } finally {
            notes.close();
        }

    }
```

main.xml, containing the listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<Button
android:id="@+id/new_note_button"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:text="@string/new_note"/>
<ListView
android:id="@android:id/list"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/empty"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:text="@string/empty"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: also check that your list view is set to enabled, clickable and focusable.

Comment: FYI `android:id="@+id/empty"` should be `android:id="@android:id/empty"`

Comment: onItemClick is not called. and setting the listview to clickable and focusable didn't help.

Comment: just add some logs in onitemclick event and see that log is printed or not?thats how you know whthr prob. in click or in toast

Comment: I did that already, that's how I know it isn't called.

Comment: also checked using a breakpoint in the debugger

Comment: could it possibly have something to do with the layout of the items?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing is missing, your code is completely correct, just replace the getApplicationContext() to "this" could probably solve the problem, as what you need to pass is a reference to the context of the current component rather than the context of the current process.

Hope it helps.
Hass.

Comment: Does it need to be `Notes.this`?

Comment: well, it isn't an issue with the makeText call, as before I had a simple Log.d call in its place and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your list item is set clickable. (view.setClickable(true))

onItemClick will to be called when the list item is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:focusable="false"` to the button you have in your main.xml file. The button is taking the focus away from the list item.

This is solve your problem for sure.

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend throwing something like this in your try statement

```
try{
    //yourstuff
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And then check to see what error message is thrown.  It's possible that it's throwing the error when it sets the onClickListener, maybe there's something invalid, but as long as all of that is in a try statement, it's not going to give you any helpful error message.  So you could also just pull as much out of the try statement as possible until you find the problem. :-)